# Typeorm UpdateValuesMissingError: Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, typeorm

## Typeorm UpdateValuesMissingError: Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated...

i got that error when I'm trying to create and save the order

I encountered the "TypeORM UpdateValuesMissingError" while attempting to create and save orders in my application. Below is the code snippet of my order controller, followed by the Order entity schema and the Shop entity schema:

`this is the order controller:`

````
        country: orderData.shippingAddress.country,
        city: orderData.shippingAddress.city,
        street: orderData.shippingAddress.street,
        region: orderData.shippingAddress.region,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: userIn,
      });

      await transactionManager.save(userAddress);

      // Create orders for each shop
      const orders: Order[] = [];
      for (const [shopId, variantsForShop] of shopVariantsMap.entries()) {
        console.log(`Processing shop with ID: ${shopId}`);
        console.log(`Variants for shop:`, variantsForShop);

        const shop = await Shop.findOne({ where: { shop_id: shopId }, select: ['shop_id'] });
        if (shop) {
          const totalPrice = variantsForShop.reduce((acc, variant) => {
            const orderDetail = orderData.orderDetails.find((detail) => detail.variant_id === variant.variant_id);
            if (orderDetail) {
              return acc + orderDetail.quantity * variant.discountPrice;
            }
            return acc;
          }, 0);

          console.log(`Total price for shop with ID ${shopId}:`, totalPrice);

          const quantity = variantsForShop.reduce((acc, variant) => {
            const orderDetail = orderData.orderDetails.find((detail) => detail.variant_id === variant.variant_id);
            if (orderDetail) {
              return acc + orderDetail.quantity;
            }
            return acc;
          }, 0);

          console.log(`Total quantity for shop with ID ${shopId}:`, quantity);

          if (variantsForShop.length === 0) {
            console.log(`Variants for shop with ID ${shopId} is empty. Skipping order creation.`);
            continue; // Skip creating order if variants are empty
          }

          console.log(`Creating order for shop with ID ${shopId}`);

          const order = Order.create({
            user: userIn,
            shop: shop,
            variants: variantsForShop,
            quantity: quantity,
            totalPrice: totalPrice,
            fullName: orderData.fullName,
            phoneNumber: orderData.phoneNumber,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            status: 'pending',
            shippingAddress: userIn?.address
          });

          await transactionManager.save(order);
          orders.push(order);
        } else {
          console.log(`Shop with ID ${shopId} not found. Skipping order creation.`);
        }
      }

      return orders;
    });


import { BaseEntity, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, OneToOne, JoinColumn, ManyToMany } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User.js";
import { Address } from "./Address.js";
import { Shop } from "./Shop.js";
import { ProductVariant } from "./ProductVariants.js";

@Entity('orders')
export class Order extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 255, nullable: false })
    fullName: string;

    @Column({ length: 255, nullable: false })
    phoneNumber: string;

    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: ['pending', 'shipping', 'completed', 'cancelled', 'refunded', 'failed'],
        default: 'pending'
    })
    status: 'pending' | 'shipping' | 'completed' | 'cancelled' | 'refunded' | 'failed';

    @Column({ nullable: false, type: 'float' })
    quantity: number

    @Column({ nullable: false, type: 'float' })
    totalPrice: number

    @OneToOne(() => Address, address => address.user)
    @JoinColumn()
    shippingAddress: Address

    @ManyToMany(() => Shop, shop => shop.orders)
    shop: Partial<Shop>

    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.orders)
    user: Partial<User>

    @OneToMany(() => ProductVariant, productVariant => productVariant.variant_id)
    variants: Partial<ProductVariant>[]

    @CreateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamp',
        default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)"
    })
    createdAt: Date;
}


import { BaseEntity, BeforeInsert, Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, JoinColumn, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToMany, OneToOne, ManyToMany, JoinTable } from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { Product } from "./Product.js";
import { Address } from "./Address.js";
import { Order } from "./Order.js";
import { VerificationCode } from "./VerificationCode.js";

@Entity('shops')
export class Shop extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    shop_id: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', default: "https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/84/165/png-clipart-united-states-avatar-organization-information-user-avatar-service-computer-wallpaper-thumbnail.png" })
    avatar: string;

    @Column({ length: 255, nullable: false })
    shopName: string;

    @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
    description: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false, unique: true })
    email: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    async hashPassword() {
        if (this.password) {
            this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
        }
    }
    @Column({ nullable: false })
    password: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true, unique: true })
    phoneNumber: string

    @Column({ nullable: false, default: false })
    isVerified: boolean;

    @Column({ nullable: false, default: false })
    isDeleted: boolean;

    @Column({ nullable: false, default: 'Shop' })
    role: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Product, products => products.shop)
    products: Partial<Product>[]

    @ManyToMany(() => Order, order => order.shop)
    @JoinTable()
    orders: Partial<Order>[]

    @OneToOne(() => VerificationCode, verificationCode => verificationCode.shop, { onUpdate: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'verification_code_id' })
    verificationCode: Partial<VerificationCode>

    @CreateDateColumn({
        type: 'timestamp',
        default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)"
    })
    createdAt: Date;
}```

> I believe the issue lies in the relationships defined in the entities,
> but I'm unsure how to resolve it. I've tried different solutions, such
> as adding { cascade: true } to the ProductVariant relationship, but to
> no avail.
> 
> In the order controller, I create orders for each shop by iterating
> over a map of shop variants. Each order includes details like the
> user's shipping address, total price, and quantity. I then attempt to
> save each order using TypeORM's transaction manager.
> 
> Here's how the relevant parts of the entities are set up:
> 
> Order Entity: Contains fields like fullName, phoneNumber, quantity,
> totalPrice, and relationships with Shop, User, Address, and
> ProductVariant. Shop Entity: Includes fields like shopName, email,
> phoneNumber, and relationships with Product, Order, and
> VerificationCode. I suspect there might be an issue with how the
> many-to-many relationship between Order and Shop is defined, or
> perhaps with how the entities are associated during the creation and
> saving of orders.
> 
> Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be
> greatly appreciated. Thank you!
````